# Facebook Open Graph API explorer offline_access tokens cant be ticked

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I've recently been working on a project which gets data from the Facebook open graph API. All works fine except after a few hours it stops working and my token is no longer valid. Did some research and under extended permissions I need to tick offline_access so that my tokens last longer. I ticked offline access but the token i'm given still only lasts 2 hours and if I go back to check my permissions again it is still unticked. Done this over and over again and cant tick offline_access in the open graph API explorer.

Is anybody else experiencing this problem ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Offline Access isn't supported for new apps and will be removed from existing apps soon, see here https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/ for the migration information

Comment: Thanks for the quick response,it says i can get 'long lived' tokens instead of the now obsolete offline_access tokens which last 60 days does any one know how i can obtain theese ?

Comment: This is explained on that document, depending on whether you already have some users who've granted offline_access you need to look at either Scenario 2 or 4, i guess 4 in your case